# how to make cronjob authentification?

Tags: php, authentication, cron

I want every day to check my database and do some staff with it. Cronjob is amazing solution. But how to make authentification? Otherwise anyone can trigger that code at any time. Thank you.
For example usually person must insert login and password, get token and store it in cookies. After that you have rights to change anything. How to make it in cronjob.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: What have tried so far..?

Answer (score 0):

add cron job in is such way so that php file run from CLI.Don't run it by sending http request.Command for running as CLI will be like  `php test.php`

and add the following code in the php file so that it is only allowed to run from CLI:

```
if (php_sapi_name() == "cli") die('run only from CLI');
```